# Can a gas be modelled as a low density blackbody, if we want to consider how detectable it will be in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, astronomy

The answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/158231/what-parameters-control-the-amount-of-thermal-energy-an-object-must-possess-for) taught me about the sort of parameters I need to consider if I want to consider how "detectable" an object in space is.

I want to consider the detectability of a spacecraft's exhaust. In the case of a chemical rocket engine, the exhaust is a gas composed of the products of an exothermic chemical reaction. Could I thus model the exhaust as a single low density blackbody? An ion thruster is similar, since the exhaust is a "gas" of ionized particles.

Somehow, though, treating the exhaust as a small blackbody feels like it could potentially be quite problematic. Is the assumption fine?